# How to mock static methods of a Laravel Eloquent model?

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, eloquent, mockery

I have in my code a line like this:

```
ModelName::create($data);
```

where ModelName is just an `Eloquent` model. Is there a way to mock this call inside a unit test? I tried with:

```
$client_mock = \Mockery::mock('Eloquent','App\Models\ModelName');
$client_mock->shouldReceive('create')
            ->with($data)->andReturns($returnValue);
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Is it a typo? `->andReturn(...);`

Answer (score 19):

You should do something like this:

```
$client_mock = \Mockery::mock('overload:App\Models\ModelName');
$client_mock->shouldReceive('create')->with($data)->andReturn($returnValue);
```

We are using `overload:` because you don't want to pass mock to some class, but you want to use it also in case it's hard-coded into some classes.

In addition to your test class (just before `class`) you should add:

```
/**
 * @runTestsInSeparateProcesses
 * @preserveGlobalState disabled
 */
```

to avoid errors that this class was already loaded (it might work without it in single test but when you are running multiple tests probably it won't).

You might read [Mocking hard dependencies](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/cookbook/mocking_hard_dependencies.html) for details about it.

**UPDATE**

In some cases it might be not possible to mock classes using this method. In those cases you can create a normal mock (without `overload`) and inject it to the service container like so:

```
App::instance('\App\Models\ModelName', $client_mock);
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried with your approach, but this is what I get back `Mockery\Exception\RuntimeException: Could not load mock App\Models\ModelName, class already exists` . I've added @runTestsInSeparateProcesses and @preserveGlobalState as well.

Comment: @Zed You should make sure it's a very first line in your test. In case you already so something else with ModelName - either directly in method or in other places (for example `setUp` method) it won't work because it will first create real object and won't be able to overload it next time.

Comment: When mocking public static method calls you should use `alias:App\Models\ModelName` not `overload:\Models\ModelName`. `overload` is used to intercept and mock class instantiation (new class() for instance) and `alias` is used for public static methods (Class::method).

Comment: @Zed If you still have this problem, you might look at my updated answer

Comment: Worked a bit for me :-)

Comment: `/**
     * @runInSeparateProcess
     * @preserveGlobalState disabled
     */`